# Как узнать координаты сторон обьекта?

Tags: unity3d

У меня имеется прямоугольник. Нужно определить координаты его сторон в коде( х - для правой и левой, у - для верхней и нижней).Знаю про некоторые встроенные функции bounds.extents. Но это не то.Что делать?

Comment: Игровой движок Unity3D. У прямоугольника имеется Renderer. Имеются коорды центра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно узнать размеры Вашего прямоугольника. Если тип меша - `Quad`, то его `localScale` по `x,y` задает линейные размеры в мировых координатах (изначально стороны `Quad`'a равны единице).

Т.е.

`width = transform.localScale.x // ширина
 height = transform.localScale.y // высота`

Пусть `(xc, yc)` - координаты центра.

`xl = xc - width/2 //"левый" x
 xr = xc + width/2 //"правый" x`

Для `y` - так же (в мировой системе координат ось Oy идет снизу вверх).

`yt = yc + height/2 //"верхний" y
 yb = yc - height/2 //"нижний" y`

Таким образом,

`(xc - width/2, yc + height/2) - левый верхний угол
 (xc + width/2, yc - height/2) - правый нижний`

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил:) Для конкретики нужен тип Вашей модели.

Answer (score 0):

Если это надо чисто из интереса, создайте пустой `GameObject`, зажмите клавишу `V` и поднесите его к нужной стороне.